# How to ignore MFA Authentication in AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-cognito

I'm using AuthFlow='ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH' to set up Cognito MFA authentication.

I wonder if Is there any way that I can ignore the MFA authentication?

Which AdminInitiateAuth request should I use?

For example:

I create a user, then register that user to my UserPool, enable MFA for that user, and now MFA is working fine.

But what if on a bad day, I don't want to use MFA Authentication anymore, but I also don't want to disable MFA for my user because I want to use it on another beautiful day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May not be the answer you are hoping for but... You can't do it. And it wouldn't even make sense.

The MFA is either enable or disabled. If it's enabled, you need to authenticated with it. Think about it. You set it up to protect user's account. But the user is able to say - oh, I actually don't want to use it just this time.
The thing is - a bad actor could do exactly the same. Just send a request saying not to use MFA. That would defeat the purpose of MFA entirely.

That's why this decision is left to either an administrator of the pool or the user who can disable it, but only as long as he/she is signed it (depending on pool's configuration).

That's why you can only either have it enabled or disabled. And you cannot disable it ad hoc per request.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand your concern, but what I really want is enable or disable MFA is not decided by or for a specific user, but by our admin and for the whole User Pool.

What I want is something like: 

- When admin update config use_mfa = true => send a request to update User Pool config to enable MFA authentication for all users.

- When admin update config use_mfa= false => send a request to update User Pool config to NOT use MFA, but use username/password authentication instead for all users.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you need `SetUserPoolMfaConfig` (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_SetUserPoolMfaConfig.html).

Comment: Yes, this one is exactly what I need. Thank you so much

Comment: Hi guys!
@AleksanderWons is right if you have enabled MFA you don't want to disable that. But what if you have server-side connection that cannot provide MFA. Let's say a nodejs or python application that want to call an api with the username/password in the userpool but the mfa is enabled.